# WYGWAM Cyrillic

Tags: wygwam

I'm trying to create a post on russian and after typing anything and clicking source I see this stuff:

```
<p>&#1057;&#1090;&#1072;&#1076;&#1080;&#1086;&#1085; &#1073;&#1099;&#1083; &#1087;&#1086;&#1083;&#1085;&#1099;&#1081;, &#1085;&#1077; &#1087;&#1088;&#1086;&#1089;&#1090;&#1086; &#1087;&#1086;&#1083;&#1085;&#1099;&#1081;, &#1072; &#1087;&#1077;&#1088;&#1077;&#1087;&#1086;&#1083;&#1085;&#1077;&#1085;&#1085;&#1099;&#1081;, &#1083;&#1102;&#1076;&#1080; &#1089;&#1084;&#1086;&#1090;&#1088;&#1077;&#1083;&#1080; &#1089;&#1090;&#1086;&#1103;, &#1085;&#1072; &#1074;&#1093;&#1086;&#1076;&#1077;, &#1074;&#1099;&#1096;&#1077; &#1089;&#1080;&#1076;&#1103;&#1095;&#1080;&#1093; &#1084;&#1077;&#1089;&#1090;, &#1103; &#1073;&#1099;&#1083; &#1087;&#1088;&#1080;&#1103;&#1090;&#1085;&#1086; &#1091;&#1076;&#1080;&#1074;&#1083;&#1077;&#1085;, &#1095;&#1090;&#1086; &#1087;&#1088;&#1080;&#1096;&#1083;&#1086; &#1089;&#1090;&#1086;&#1083;&#1100;&#1082;&#1086; &#1083;&#1102;&#1076;&#1077;&#1081; &#1087;&#1086;&#1076;&#1076;&#1077;&#1088;&#1078;&#1072;&#1090;&#1100; &#1089;&#1074;&#1086;&#1081; &#1082;&#1083;&#1091;&#1073;!</p>
```

I see the same while viewing source code on the website :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, that's normal and correct, relating to how CKEditor (used as the backbone for Wygwam) handles the content and seems to store it in its character encoding, but items like text fields store it in the native (as is) format.

Why is it an issue if the visual result is correct?

These solutions may help:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510434/data-in-db-is-in-wrong-encoding-using-ckeditor-and-greek

http://forum.pivotx.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=3267

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust that behavior by going to Add-Ons > Modules > Wygwam > [your config name], and adding the ‘entities’ and maybe ‘entities_greek’ + ‘entities_latin’ advanced config settings, and setting them to ‘No’.